# What are the long-term effects of arnica used to treat a tendinopathy?

Tags: tendinopathy, natural-remedy

What are the long-term effects of arnica used to treat a tendinopathy? I am mostly interested in treatment effectiveness as well as the long-term impact on the tendon and its surroundings. I am mostly interested in epicondylitis (a.k.a. epicondylopathy, tennis/golfer elbow, enthesopathy).

(1) gives some encouraging results but only looks at short term outcomes (21 days) with a small sample size (8 adults), and is not that much [CONSORT](http://www.consort-statement.org/) compliant:

[image]

---

(1) Silva, Ary Gomes, Elbe Rodrigues Machado, Leonardo Mendes Almeida, Ricardo Marcelo Menezes Nunes, Patrícia Caldeira Pena Giesbrecht, Regina Mamed Costa, Helber B. Costa, Wanderson Romão, and Ricardo Machado Kuster. "A clinical trial with Brazilian arnica (Solidago chilensis Meyen) glycolic extract in the treatment of tendonitis of flexor and extensor tendons of wrist and hand." Phytotherapy Research 29, no. 6 (2015): 864-869. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=15532124240869151624&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22 ; http://sci-hub.cc/10.1002/ptr.5323#

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.